# Handling try catch

Tags: iphone, exception, try-catch, xcode4.5

My project is service oriented and everything comes from services.I m loading the data in UILabel's,tableviews etc.When particular text doesn't come from service then I dont want to show null there ,neither display that view.So I want to redirect it some other view which displays an error image.But @try ,@catch are not working.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  //activity indicator code
  [self performSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

  NSString *name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.provName];
  CGSize constraint1 = CGSizeMake(250, 2000.0f);
  CGSize size1 = [name sizeWithFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18] constrainedToSize:constraint1 lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
  self. pName =[[UILabel alloc] init];
  @try {
    if([name length]>0
    {
      self.pName.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,name];
    }
    else
    {
      NSException *exception = [NSException
                                  exceptionWithName:@""
                                  reason:@""
                                  userInfo:nil];
      @throw exception;
    } 
  }

  @catch (NSException *exception) {
    ErrorView *errorView=[[ErrorView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ErrorView" bundle:nil];
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue]<5.0)
    {
      [self presentModalViewController:errorView animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
      [self presentViewController:errorView animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
    [errorView release];
  }
}

- (void) threadStartAnimating
{
   //other code

}
```

But even when the text length is zero its not redirected to errorView.Instead rest of code in the current View is being executed.

I couldn't understand where I m going wrong?

Comment: Why use `@try`/`@catch` at all here?  This can be achieved using `if`/`else`...

Comment: But sometimes during checking for array count I need to use try/catch .So i thought of following the same everywhere

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions like this; see: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#exceptions

Comment: I just tried out the exception-handling logic of this code, and it works, throwing an exception for zero-length strings. What symptoms are you seeing? If you put a breakpoint in the `@catch` block, does it get hit?

Comment: @trojanfoe from the linked article: "Programs which do care about recovering from exceptions should enable the option." and in this case recovery _is_ expected. It's true that the usual convention for exceptions in Cocoa is to reserve them for programmer error, but that's not the same as saying they should _not_ be used.

Comment: @GrahamLee it gets hit.But it doesn't redirect to ErrorView and moreover the rest of the code after catch block is being executed .

Comment: @GrahamLee I don't believe it's reasonable to signal error using them when a simple test will suffice.  They are expensive and don't add any value.  It's a little like detecting an error and signalling it to the caller by writing a file; while this will work, you wouldn't and shouldn't do it.

Comment: @arizah what does "doesn't redirect to ErrorView" mean? Is `-initWithNibName:bundle:` not being called? And _what_ code after the `@catch` block?

Comment: @GrahamLee yes initWithNibName:bundle is not being called.I have checked the nibname and no where spell mistake is..After catch block self.pName.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
     self.pName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
     
         self.pName.textColor=UIColorFromRGB(COLOR_BLUE);

    [ self.pName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18]];
    [testscroll addSubview: self.pName]; When catch block is executed UIView is not loaded and statements after catch block are exceuted I get the current view only

Comment: Is `ErrorView` a `UIView` subclass or `UIViewController` subclass?  If the latter then is `view` correctly linked in the NIB?  Is `errorView`  non-`nil`?  This question isn't about try/catch at all.

Comment: ErrorView  is UIViewController subclass

Comment: @trojanfoe Attempt to present <ErrorView: 0xa427ad0> on <ViewController: 0xbc84200> whose view is not in the window hierarchy! is the warning in console area

Comment: This is the question you should be asking.  I would delete this question and start a new one.